# I extended myClass about drawer class, I see layout myClass but I cannot click in buttons

Tags: java, android, menu, navigation, drawer

I have code like this:

DrawerLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawerList"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:entries="@array/Functions" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

DrawerActivity:

```
public class Drawer extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private Intent intent;
    public RelativeLayout fullLayout;
    public FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

        fullLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        drawerList = (ListView) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);


        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);

        super.setContentView(fullLayout);

        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Functions)));
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {}
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){}
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                intent = new Intent(this, 0Act.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                // intent = new Intent(this, 1Act.class);
                break;
            case 2:
                intent = new Intent(this, 2Act.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 3:
                intent = new Intent(this, 3Act.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 4:
                // intent = new Intent(this, 4Act.class);
                break;
        }
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
}
```

FirstActivity:

```
            public class 0Act extends Drawer implements ActionBar.TabListener {
            ActionBar.Tab t1,t2,t3;
            ActionBar actionBar;
    Button oneButton;
        final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
        AlertDialog.Builder ad;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.0Act);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


                t1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("1");
                t2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("2");
                t3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("3");

                t1.setTabListener(this);
                t2.setTabListener(this);
                t3.setTabListener(this);

                actionBar.addTab(t1);
                actionBar.addTab(t2);
                actionBar.addTab(t3);
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);

    oneButton= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.oneButton);
            oneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){@Override public void onClick(View v) {ad.show();}});

             ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
             ad.setTitle("Menu");
             ad.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {}});

            }
  }
```

I see the drawer - I can click on the drawer but I cannot click on any buttons from the first activity. What is going wrong?
Before added drawer to many activities all working good but now I dont see any error and activity dont working.

Comment: Do you have set some clickListener for you button ?

Comment: Question is not proper, Item1Activity extending BaseActivity, and you haven't added the BaseActvitiy class, you have added BaseDrawerActivity, and you're expecting solution from the question? add the layouts code too

Answer (score 0):

Mention super.onClick(v); inside onClick method for your Item1Activity Class